# Crucial Drupal Modules for Dynamic Site Development

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-modules

I have spent the last few days playing around with Drupal for the first time, and I really like it. Especially after building dynamic sites from scratch.

Being that there are thousands of modules, I would like to know what modules SO users cant live (or develop) without.

What modules do you **always** (*or always with specific requirements*) use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some great posts out there with lists of can't-live-without modules:  http://delicious.com/search?p=top+drupal+modules&chk=&fr=del_icio_us&lc=1&sd=6M&ed=&atags=drupal&context=all||

Personally though:

- Admin Menu
- Views
- CCK
- Pathauto (and Token)
- Adminrole
- Redirect 403 to User Login
- Global Redirect

Other modules I use a lot but not necessarily every single site, depending on the needs:

- Imagefield
- Imagecache
- Quicktabs
- Print
- Flag
- Webform

Answer (score 2):

I install these regardless of the site, regardless of the requirements, and before I do *anything* else:

- [Admin Menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu)
- [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck)
- [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)

Comment: +1 for Admin Menu, just installed it and love it. Any more useful time-savers?

Answer (score 0):

What Dave DeLong said.

Also, some helpful mods:

- Contemplate (Content Templates)
- Devel (if you're going to develop your own Drupal theme)

http://drupalmodules.com/ is the best site for finding Drupal modules.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to what Dave DeLong has suggested, I also highly recommend the following:

- Advanced Forum - for decent looking forums, in case you want them
- Wikitools + Freelinking - for wiki-like link behaviour
- Google Analytics - for using this great Google service
- Wysiwyg - easy post editing using a graphical WYSIWYG interface

Other tools are mostly specific to the functions you want to have on your site.

Answer (score 0):

I know that a million people are going to jump on this thread, but anyhoo...

Your best bet is to take a look at the [usage statistics](http://drupal.org/project/usage) for each module. You talk with ten different people and you'll get ten different lists of "must have" modules, but these statistics demonstrate what people actually use. I would just start at the top and work your way down the list - even if you hit something that you don't need, it will be worth the time you take to understand what it does.

Oh, and Sam is very right: the best place to SEARCH for modules is [drupalmodules.com](http://drupalmodules.com).

Answer (score 0):

- [SEO Checklist](http://drupal.org/project/seo_checklist)
- [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler)
- [XML sitemap](http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap)

Answer (score 0):

Some I love but haven't seen mentioned yet:

- FCKEditor:
  http://drupal.org/project/fckeditor
- Taxonomy Menu (on some sites):
  http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu

Answer (score 0):

I use also ThemeKey for change theme using taxonomy or regex.